# How to use gtkmm in Netbeans or Eclipse

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, netbeans, gtkmm

Hi Stackoverflow community, I hope everything is fine.
You may be saying"there is a lot of posts on this already", but here is the thing. I still haven't resolve my problem of not being able to compile a class with gtkmm, yes after reading everything. I currently have, Ubuntu 16.04.
As the title says, I want to know how to get gtkmm working with eclipse or netbeans please I beg you, do it with all the details possible. I could get it working in Ubuntu terminal(who by default brings the gtkmm and c++ compiler pre-installed), the case is that I want an IDE to have gtkmm because if in any moment I develop a program that has more than 5 classes I would have to compile all the files in the terminal. Which in exchange having an IDE with these tools is a better option for a bigger program.

Things that I have done: I've installed pkg-config and selected gtkmm-3.0 option in eclipse it just give thousands of errors in the console plus saying that some files are missing and when I tell eclipse where is it, it just says there is another file missing and the chain continues. 
In netbeans it just give me (BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 7s)) error and much more like this make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2. And like 10 solutions additional these, if you have any questions please tell me.

Sorry for the large post, thanks for reading and have a nice day.

Comment: _To improve your chances of getting [a helpful] answer_, follow [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Including the error message for one of the installation procedures tried is constructive - just make it stand out more using a _block quote_. Welcome to Stack Overflow! (where [salutations are considered chit-chat](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior))

Comment: Thanks man it helped me understand more about the page :)
I was so desperate that I thought that if I include every detail, maybe someone could help. Keeping away comments like "There is already post about this...." Thanks for the welcoming me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can see this post about [how to configure netbeans IDE for gtkmm on linux](https://gtkmm-tutorial.blogspot.com/2016/06/how-to-configure-netbeans-ide-for-gtkmm-on-linux.html)
the example in the post use ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Thank you very much manneta, it solve the problem in one try! :D

Comment: Wow, that works. A doubt though, that tutorial is created in 2016, now is 2019. He chooses C++11, and now we have C++14. Is it ok for me to choose C++14 instead of old C++11? @manneta